# Destroy / Discard entries before validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a simple ToDo app with Task model (title:string, due:datetime).

I'm trying to use a before_validation callback to prevent my app from adding (or not validating) empty tasks but have no idea how to achieve that. It's important for me to make it before_validation because there are some validation rules i need to use on my tasks.

So, here i've tried doing this that way:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :remove_empty_tasks

  def remove_empty_tasks
    if self.title.empty? && self.due.empty?
      self.destroy
    end
  end
end
```

But it's not working. All other possible solutions i've found on the internet were not helpfull neither. Can you please give me some advice what is the proper way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: a validation return TRUE or FALSE, so instead of `self.destroy`, just do `return false`

Comment: Are you using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in Project.rb ? It has a `reject_if ` option. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :remove_empty_tasks

  def remove_empty_tasks
    if self.title.blank? && self.due.blank?
      self.errors.add(:title, 'Should not be empty!')
    end
  end
end
```

With this configuration:

```
 Task.create(title: '', due: Date.today) 
  #=> does not create the task (title is empty)
 Task.create(title: 'Bonjour') 
  #=> does not create the task (due is nil)
 Task.create(title: 'Aurevoir', due: Date.today) 
  #=> passes the custom validation 'remove_empty_tasks'
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising but it's not working. My tasks are still saving to the db.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use `validates_presence_of` ?

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :title
  validates_presence_of :due
end
```

Comment: use the Rails 3 -way: `validates :title, presence: true` ;)

Comment: Well, i can't use that solution because it will return me a validation error when i'll try to save tasks (it's a nested form).I don't want it to work this way, i need to remove empty tasks silently.

Comment: @mbajur in that case simply ignore invalid tasks in your controller